# data structure programming algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

how to draw binary trees whose preorder listing is abcdefgh and whose postorder listing is dcbgfhea.also,list the nodes of binary trees in inorder and level order ?

Comment: Preorder and postorder are ways to *traverse* a tree. You still have the same underlying tree, you just traverse it differently. See: [Tree traversal on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

Answer (score 4):

Tree:

```
            a
           /  \
          b    e
         /    / \
        c    f   h
       /    / 
      d    g
```

inorder:

dcbagfeh

level order (i.e BFS):

abecfhdg

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple Python program that generates all possible inorder listings based on preorder and postorder listings.

```
from itertools import product

def inorders(pre, pos):
  if not pre: return [""]
  ret = []
  if pre[0] == pos[-1]:
    for left_size in range(len(pre)):
      left = inorders(pre[1:left_size+1], pos[:left_size])
      right = inorders(pre[left_size+1:], pos[left_size:-1])
      for l, r in product(left, right):
        ret.append(l + pre[0] + r)
  return ret
```

And here's the output for your case:

```
>>> inorders("abcdefgh", "dcbgfhea")
['bcdafgeh', 'bcdagfeh', 'bdcafgeh', 'bdcagfeh', 'cdbafgeh', 'cdbagfeh', 'dcbafgeh', 'dcbagfeh']
```

Comment: since you don't ever use `n`, you can just replace the first two lines of `inorder` with `if not pre: return ['']`

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth - I used `n` twice, but I made the change anyways. Thanks.